# PNG background color inadvertantly changes in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, includegraphics, png

below screenshot of the same image showing (left) the image as desired in a generic image viewer and (right) after inclusion with XeLaTex and `includegraphics`. i remember having to deal with something similar years ago but googling did not bring anything relevant to light. anybody know how to get XeLaTex/`includegraphics` to **not** change the image background?

[image]

Comment: Is it a transparent png? Is the page background involved?

Comment: @rallg afaics, no. as can be seen the 'background' of the image simply white. the page background (in beamer) is also simply white/default.

Answer (score 0):

so, turns out that color profiles may wreak some havoc here; following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578367/63037 solved that problem, though.

Comment: So it seems, the question is a duplicate …

Comment: Some graphics programs (such as GIMP) add a color profile by default, unless you explicitly request no profile. If you have an image with a color profile attached, it can be removed by ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick (option -strip). This also removes private metadata. Unless you have a very good reason not to strip images, do it.